# Who is ultimately responsible for setting URLResourceValues for URLs on disk?

Tags: ios, swift

Who is ultimately responsible for setting `URLResourceValues` for `URL` objects that go on disk? When I create a file on disk, `creationDate` and `contentAccessDate` are automatically set for me, but `contentAccessDate` doesn't appear to ever change on its own when I access their paths. I can update the values manually with `setResourceValues()` but am I supposed to? And why does `creationDate` have a setter? Shouldn't that value strictly be set by the system?

Quick links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues/1779762-contentaccessdate

Comment: **Beginning in macOS 10.13, iOS 11, watchOS 4, tvOS 11, and later, contentAccessDateKey is read-write. Attempts to set a value for this file resource property on earlier systems are ignored.** If they provided a way to set it as you see above if you are on iOS11 or later you are allowed to set the contentAccess as needed. Regarding the system doing it or not probably depends on each system.

Comment: `extension URL {     var contentAccess: Date? {
        get {
            return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.contentAccessDateKey]))?.contentAccessDate
        }
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.contentAccessDate = newValue
            try? setResourceValues(resourceValues)
        }
    } }`